# Can I create a prototype for a variadic Python function using ctypes so that a DLL can call this function as a callback?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes, variadic

Here's the scenario:  I am using ctypes to load a C DLL into a Python program.  I want to register a callback so that code in the DLL can call a function in Python.

This is all great until I want to have the function be variadic.  For example, say I wanted to implement "printf" in Python (for argument's sake, I'll also have it return an integer):

```
def printf(format, *args):
    (...)
    return 0
```

I am creating the callback function pointer using the CFUNCTYPE factory in ctypes:

```
callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_wchar_p)
```

Of course, since I only specify one input argument (the format string as a Unicode char array), the callback works but `*args` is empty.

So, is there any way of making this work with ctypes, or do I need to rewrite my C code to not require a variadic callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not supported by the underlying libffi.  You need indeed to write custom C code.

(Fwiw, [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/) is a ctypes alternative.  Also based on libffi, it suffers from the same limitation --- but at least it makes it easy to write custom pieces of C code to do the interfacing.)

Comment: Edited the documentation of CFFI to have an example with a custom callback written in C, itself calling back to Python.