# Can Cython be used to define C-callable variadic functions?

Tags: python, c, cython, ctypes, variadic-functions

I'm writing [a Python library](https://github.com/JesseTG/libretro.py) for testing DLLs that implement a particular C API. This library also exposes functionality to the native DLLs through callback functions fetched at runtime. There's a specific function I'd like to implement, and it's declared like so:

```c
enum retro_log_level; // definition omitted for brevity

// typedef for a printf-like function
typedef void (RETRO_CALLCONV *retro_log_printf_t)(enum retro_log_level level, const char *fmt, ...);

struct retro_log_callback
{
   // defined in Python, called by C
   retro_log_printf_t log;
};
```

The problem is that `retro_log_printf_t` is variadic, [and therefore cannot be implemented with `ctypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867473/can-i-create-a-prototype-for-a-variadic-python-function-using-ctypes-so-that-a-d). I didn't design or implement this API, so I can't change it.

One idea I had was to implement `retro_log_printf_t` in C (or similar) so that I can bypass the linked `ctypes` limit. I'm considering Cython for this, but I don't know if that's possible.

So my question is this: **How can I use Cython to declare and implement a variadic function that can be called from C and is compatible with the aforementioned `retro_log_printf_t`?**

Comment: _If_ the C API is going to be used [purely] by C programs, it seems strange to me to add extra functionality to just write a test suite in python. I'd write the unit tests for the C API in C. Already what you're describing seems more complex and difficult than the tests themselves. So, I'd rewrite the `retro_log_printf_t` in C. You're already encountering needless/extra complexity for a _test_ suite. If you must, another scripting language that interfaces to C more easily might be a better choice (e.g. `perl`, `lua`, `raku`, etc.)

Comment: It's documented in the Cython FAQ (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/faq.html#how-do-i-use-variable-args) so I assume it's possible. With that said I've never seen it used, and it isn't covered by any of Cython's tests, so be a little cautious.

Comment: @CraigEstey The Python code I'm writing is standing in for [a frontend that's typically written in C](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch). (There are multiple frontends, but RetroArch is the most popular.) I've already tried writing tests that use this frontend directly, but they don't afford the flexibility I want.

Comment: FYI: You *can* call variadic functions with `ctypes`, just not variadic callbacks. For example, `printf.argtypes = c_char_p,` ensures the first parameter is a `char*`, but additional parameters can be added, but may need to be constructed explicitly to be marshalled correctly, e.g., `printf(b'%f\n', ct.c_double(456.125))`.  But it's true that  callbacks can't be variadic because the argument types need to be known in advance by the `ctypes` wrapper.

Comment: Just a thought: Why leave it to the callback routine(s) to deal with *fmt*` and `varargs`?  Ideally the C API should generate the final string once and pass that to the callback instead of individual callbacks each having to do it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I agree (in fact, I do that in [my own libretro implementation](https://github.com/JesseTG/melonds-ds)), but I'd prefer not to assume that users of the C API will always do so.